# Python cgi performance

Tags: python, performance, cgi

I own a legacy python application written as CGI. Until now this works OK, but the number of concurrent users will increment largely in the very near future.
Here on SO I read: "CGI is great for low-traffic websites, but it has some performance problems for anything else". I know it would have been better to start in another way, but CGI is what is is now.

Could someone point me a direction on to how to keep the CGI performing, without having to rewrite all code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CGI doesn't scale because each request forks a brand new server process.  It's a lot of overhead.  mod_wsgi avoid the overhead by forking one process and handing requests to that one running process.

Let's assume the application is the worst kind of cgi.

The worst case is that it has files like this.

`my_cgi.py`

```
import cgi
print "status: 200 OK"
print "content-type: text/html"
print
print "<!doctype...>"
print "<html>"
etc.
```

You can try to "wrap" the original CGI files to make it wsgi.

`wsgi.py`

```
import cStringIO
def my_cgi( environ, start_response ):
    page = cStringIO.StringIO()
    sys.stdout= page
    os.environ.update( environ ) 
    # you may have to do something like execfile( "my_cgi.py", globals=environ ) 
    execfile( "my_cgi.py" )
    status = '200 OK' # HTTP Status
    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html')] # HTTP Headers
    start_response(status, headers)
    return page.getvalue()
```

This a first step to rewriting your CGI application into a proper framework.  This requires very little work, and will make your CGI's much more scalable, since you won't be starting a fresh CGI process for each request.

The second step is to create a `mod_wsgi` server that Apache uses instead of all the CGI scripts.  This server must (1) parse the URL's, (2) call various function like the `my_cgi` example function.  Each function will `execfile` the old CGI script without forking a new process.

Look at [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) for helpful libraries.

If your application CGI scripts have some structure (functions, classes, etc.) you can probably import those and do something much, much smarter than the above.  A better way is this.

`wsgi.py`

```
from my_cgi import this_func, that_func
def my_cgi( environ, start_response ):

    result= this_func( some_args )
    page_text= that_func( result, some_other_args )

    status = '200 OK' # HTTP Status
    headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html')] # HTTP Headers
    start_response(status, headers)
    return page_text
```

This requires more work because you have to understand the legacy application.  However, this has two advantages.

1. It makes your CGI's more scalable because you're not starting a fresh process for each request.
2. It allows you to rethink your application, possibly changing it to a proper framework.  Once you've done this, it's not very hard to take the next step and move to [TurboGears](http://turbogears.org/) or [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/) or [web.py](http://webpy.org/) for a very simple framework.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate reply. My app is of the worst kind. 
Will there be problems with having to change calls to gi.FieldStorage(), MySQLdb and things like using the os module?

Comment: Never.  The only thing that will break when you move from bad cgi to fastcgi or mod_wsgi is the `print` statement.  The `print` statement output works for cgi, but does not work anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Use [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/). If I understand FastCGI correctly, you can do what you want by writing a very simple Python program that sits between the web server and your legacy code.